# Set the name of a file for a cronjob automatically

Tags: command-line, cron

I have the following cronjob that I have set up to run a Python script through PuTTY. The script downloads some data, imports it to a csv (the file that is given as an argument) and pushes it to my Github:

```
0 16 * * * python3 UnderdogADP.py ud_adp_05022022.csv && git add ud_adp_05022022.csv && git commit -m "Updated ADP" && git push >> adp.log
```

Is there a way to have the filename change dynamically based on the date? For example, I would want the filename today to be ud_adp_05032022.csv and tomorrow have it be ud_adp_05042022.csv, etc.? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it with this syntax:

```
0 16 * * * python3 UnderdogADP.py ud_adp_`date +%m%d%Y`.csv && git add ud_adp_`date +%m%d%Y`.csv && git commit -m "Updated ADP" && git push >> adp.log
```